# Sql reports 2008 error

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

Hello guys I am running some code too setup my report parameters but I am getting the following error in Visual Studio 2008:

> Client found response content type of '', but expected
>   'text/xml'.\r\nThe request failed with an empty response."
>   System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}

This only happened recently, I assume it is because I run sql 2008 and not 2005 like on the other machines here?

here's the line of code that error occurs on:

```
ReportParameter[] expectedParameters = 
_ReportServerClient.GetReportParameters(report, null, false, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter for rendering the content to the browser is wrong(either HTML or XML) type MIME type should be given.